# Can the ID in the ASpNetUsers table change for any reason

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I'm testing the new asp.net identity. I added a new table to the SQL database to gather more information about each subscriber (name, family name, city etc). I don't want to use the existing ASpNetUsers for that matter. I want to use 2 different tables. To identify the same subscriber in the 2 tables I'm using the Unique Identifier that is added automatically to the ASpNetUsers table. Couple of days ago I noticed that one of the ID in the ASpNetUsers has changed. Dunno how. Is that possible? Can the ID of a registered subscriber change in the ASpNetUsers table for any reason (changing password, confirming a new password etc?

Thanks

Comment: What is the name and type of the ID field you're using?

Comment: [Id] NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)

Comment: This is an example of the id in the database: b45jh3b9-343a-5dd6-a92s-84521bc9321ef

Comment: That looks like a GUID. Why not use the `Guid` type in SQL Server instead of `nvarchar`? You don't need 256 bytes for each ID that way, thus saving a lot of space.

Comment: The AspNetUsers table was added automatically when I installed the identity package. The Id column was also added automatically. I didn't configure them myself. I'm afraid to change any type in the database. The built-in package system might stop working. What do you think?

Comment: The ID should stay the same. When you change the password then the SecurityStamp changes.